# Change "and" between Authors in Citation Style Files (csl)

Tags: ms-word, citations, csl

I tried a lot to change the word "and" between two Authors using a citation programm (Papers2, Mac) and a specific citation style file (.csl), but my efforts doesnt work.
What I want to do is changing the "and" in the German "und", in both the citation inline and the reference list:

> [Shaw **and** Riha, 2012]
>
> Shaw, S. B., **and** S. J. Riha (2012), Title, J.
> Hydrol., 434-435(C), 46–54, doi:10.1016/j.jhydrol.2012.02.034.

Does anybody know how I can configure this delimiter-word in the style file?
Thanks in advance!
Micha

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best and easiest way to do this is to set the "default-locale" of this style to "de-DE" (for German), which should automatically result in the use of "und" instead of "and". See http://citationstyles.org/downloads/specification.html#the-root-element-cs-style .

Which style are you using?

Comment: I've already done this!
_<style class="in-text" version="1.0" demote-non-dropping-particle="sort-only" default-locale="de-DE" xmlns="http://purl.org/net/xbiblio/csl">_, but this does not work for me.




I'm using http://www.zotero.org/styles/american-geophysical-union

Comment: Sorry for the troubles. Could you (1) Go into the Papers Preferences > Citations, (2) Click on the popup menu 'Favorite Styles' and select 'More Styles...'. This will open the Style Browser. Then find the style of interest in the list, and then check the 'Info' tab. It should be there, and it should tell you what CSL file it's using. This is just to make sure your custom CSL file has been properly loaded. See also http://support.mekentosj.com/kb/pro-tips/pro-tip-adding-additional-citation-styles Please contact Papers support and let me know the discussion number here. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: In addition to what @charles said, did you make sure to change the style ID in your customized style?

Comment: Yes, @RintzeZelle I think that's a good idea and I suspect the main source of issue. To override a built-in style in Papers (as coming from the official repo), you need to keep both the title and the ID, or else change both to create a separate style.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the CSL file was not properly loaded into Papers. As @RintzeZelle suggested, please make sure to change both the ID and the title in your new style. To override a built-in style in Papers (as coming from the official repo), you need to keep both the title and the ID, or else change both to create a separate style. In your case, it makes sense to have a separate style for the German version. I suggest to use the id `http://www.zotero.org/styles/american-geophysical-union-german` and the title `American Geophysical Union (German)`.